# Reg Spring @Entity annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a class which has the annotation

```
@Entity(value = "mongo_collection_name", noClassnameStored = true)
public class Class_Name{ .... }
```

As you see in the above code snippet, the mongo collection name is hard coded. Can I get this value from a properties file or Consul? What should I do in order to read it from properties file or Consul?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a conf file and load them as dynamic properties using annotations `Configuration` and `PropertySource`

Follow the steps:

1. Create a conf file with the property. For example: /path/to/file.conf

```
collectionName=mongo_collection_name
```

2. Create a Configuration class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource

@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/file.conf")
class AppProperties {

}
```

3. Now you can get the value with annotation `Value` in either Service class or Application like below

```
@Value("${collectionName}")
String collectionName
```

Let me know if you have questions.